# Selenium WebDriverManger issue with browser version

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-java

I am having the same issues and setup the version in manually on but got this error message.

```
[main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector - Exception reading CfT URL ('null') to get version of chromedriver (For input string: "122.0.6261.69")
[main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient - Error HTTP 404 executing https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_122.0.6261.69
[main] WARN io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector - Exception reading https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_122.0.6261.69 to get latest version of chromedriver (Error HTTP 404 executing https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_122.0.6261.69)
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader - Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.69/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader - Extracting driver from compressed file chromedriver-win64.zip
[main] INFO io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as C:\Users\owner\.cache\selenium\chromedriver\win64\122.0.6261.69\chromedriver.exe
```

And my driver class like this:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().browserVersion("122.0.6261.69").setup()
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(),options.addArguments("--start-maximized"),options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*"),driver = new ChromeDriver(options)
```

I will appreciate you for your assistance. I have tried to solve using the suggested advice but unable to solve it.